# Javascript order on which functions are being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am still pretty new to programming and I haven't had the chance to fully understand Java or Javascript the only programming languages I know but I am trying really hard to understand Javascript.

What I am facing is that some times I do not understand when javascript is calling my created functions for example. I have created a small plugin for jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/a9gjK/1/

The plugin is very easy the images are set on top of each other using position absolute. I then take the first image and set the z-index to 100 then I take the next image and set it's z-index to 50 after this I take the first image again and fade it to 0 opacity, then I call a callback function witch sets the first image's z-index to 0 and fade it to 1 opacity and the next image's z-index to 100.

After this hole process is done the variable first is set to the next element.This is where my problem appears. If I set the variable first to the next img inside the callback function the plugin works well and everything is well, but if I do this outside the callback function after the script is ran once on each image and has to start again from the first image when it fade's out I see the background. This doesn't happen if I set the first image to next inside the callback function.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and on what topic is this related so I can read and understand better what's happening.

Comment: You should put fully-qualified URLs in your fiddle so the images appear (http://...)

Comment: I could not find where to upload the images so I tought it is not possible I will check again and correct my error thank you

Comment: Yeah, you can't upload - you have to point to your own copies on your own server. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are experiencing behavior caused by **asynchronous functions**.

jQuery animations functions like `fadeTo` execute asynchronously, which means that the function can complete any time after you call it. If you call two asynchronous functions in order,

```
asynch1();
asynch2();
```

the behavior of the code can vary because there is no guarantee that `asynch1` will execute before `asynch2`.

This is what callbacks are for. You can pass a function in that will run after the asynchronous function is completed.

When you do this,

```
$first.css({
    'z-index': 0
}).fadeTo(50, 1);
$next.css({
    'z-index': 100
});
$first = $next;
```

there is no way to predict what will happen first.

If you use a callback instead

```
$first.css({
  'z-index': 0
}).fadeTo(50, 1, function() {
  $next.css({
    'z-index': 100
  });
  $first = $next;
});
```

you know that that the `$next` css will be set after the fade animation is done.